# I'm writing an simple udf but it is showing illegal's start of expression as I am new to scala and spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
def nameFilter= (name:String):String =>{
  if(name.startsWith("A")) name
}

val register= udf(nameFilter)


concatDf.select(register(col("Region"))).show()
})

concatDf.select(ageFilter(col("Region"))).show()
```

I have concatDf where I have a column called Region and I want The Region whose name starts with "A" should be present.


O I have written the following udf. but the exception says

```
<console>:6: error: illegal start of declaration
         name.startsWith("A") name
```

Comment: You've got multiple syntax and semantic errors there, it's pretty hopeless to try to correct them all in a SO post format. I would recommend that you start with reading a some basic resources in scala syntax and code structure before jumping into writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say

> whose name starts with "A" should be present

this means that you want to use `filter` and not `select`. If you want, for example, in this table:

```
+---+-------+
|id |name   |
+---+-------+
|1  |Albania|
|2  |Germany|
+---+-------+
```

to only keep `Albania` (since it starts with A), you might want to change your logic.

To do this without UDFs (which is the best way), you can simply do:

```
df.filter(col("name").startsWith("A"))
```

But if you want to use a UDF, you still have to use `filter`, therefore you have to modify your function `nameFilter` to return a `boolean` instead of a `string`, like:

```
def nameFilter = (name: String) => name.startsWith("A")
```

Once you do that, you can use:

```
val register = udf(nameFilter)
```

To register the function, then finally:

```
df.filter(register(col("name")))
```

To actually filter the rows. Hope this is what you need, good luck!